# slow machine when waking from suspend

Tags: power-management, suspend

I am using `xfce4-power-manager` to take care of screen locking and suspend when I close the lid of my laptop. It's a great little utility!

However, when the machine wakes from suspend (which is to RAM), it is very sluggish. e.g. typing in a terminal window will incur as much as a few seconds delay.

This effectively makes suspend to RAM useless on my machine :-(

I have the same problem if I manually use `pm-suspend` or `pm-hibernate` (the latter also requiring to go through grub when it wakes up).

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Try to see if there is some program running that is confused by the suspend-resume. Issue `top` in a terminal and see if there is some program using all the CPU and/or RAM.